# TFS File comparison report tool

Tags: tfs

I often compare DEV and MAIN branches and would like to run a report to show these results.  I manually run the compare and copy and past the results into excel.  Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: How do you compare DEV and MAIN branches manually?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command line tool [tf.exe](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/folderdiff-command) to compare a visual representation of the differences between files in two server folders, in a server folder and a local folder, or in two local folders:

```
tf folderdiff sourcePath targetPath /recursive [/noprompt]
```

> /noprompt option means tf folderdiff runs without displaying user
>   interface. The output is displayed in the Command Prompt window
>   instead.